# How to vertically align a background image that has background-size: cover?

Tags: css

I have a div with a background image with background-size: cover. Is that possible to vertically align the background image on center?

I tried `background-position: left center` e `background-position: 0 50%`

here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/V8X2V/

EDIT:

Indeed `background-position: left center;` works! my problem was that I had a inline style for background, and was trying to add the background-position in a css file, for some reason it wouldn't work. But when I did put the position inline, it worked...

Comment: What doesn't work for you? Your two solutions work well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `background-position`. Something like this :

```
div {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/400/400);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background-position: 0% 30%;
}
```

---

**DEMO : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V8X2V/2/)**

Comment: Did you miss the part where the OP said he tried `background-position`?

Comment: @j08691 Just a mistake. i will delete it if the question not solved.